A markov chain question and paradox
The question is: A fair six-sided die is thrown repetitively to generate number sequences in the following way: if 1 is thrown, add 1 to the sequence and end the sequence; if 2,4,or 6 is thrown, add them to the sequence and continue throwing; if 3 or 5 is thrown, start a brand new sequence without adding 3 or 5. What is the expected sequence length.
I approached the question by letting E as the expected length we are calculating, E1 be the expected length given that the first number is 1 (which is clearly 1), E* be the expected length given that the first number is even, and E'be the expected lenght given that the first number is 3 or 5. By conditional probability, E=1/6+1/2 E*+1/3 E'
For E*, if the first number is even we add them and continue, so the expected length in this case E*=E+1; for E', if we get 3 or 5 we restart, so E'=E
Solving the equation, I get E=4, but the answer is E=2. The answer uses a cumbersome case-by-case conditional probability calculation, and it also suggests as a shortcut we can view this as a geometric distribution with success being getting 1,3 or 5. I cannot make sense of either of the argument. And I am wondering where I am wrong in my own solution. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please edit your post to use MathJax. This will make your question much easier to read and understand

It is not the case that $E^=E+1$. If you start with an even number, you may subsequently roll a $3$ or $5$, in which case you discard everything including that even number at the start. For example, the eventual sequence can have length $1$, even though the first thing you roll is an even number. In fact, you keep that first even number with probability $1/3$ (it happens whenever the first odd number after it is a $1$ rather than a $3$ or $5$). This gives you $E^=E+1/3$ which does indeed lead to $E=2$!

@JamesMartin I think that's an answer.

@JamesMartin this answers my question. Thanks!

Let $Y$ be the length of the sequence and let $X$ be the outcome of the die roll. Then note that
$$
EY = E(Y\mid X=1) P(X=1) + E(Y\mid X\in\{2,4,6\}) P(X\in\{2,4,6\}) + E(Y\mid X\in\{3,5\}) P(X\in\{3,5\})
$$
Note that
$$
E(Y\mid X=1) = 1+EY
$$
while
$$
E(Y\mid X\in\{2,4,6\}) = 1+EY
$$
and
$$
E(Y\mid X\in\{3,5\}) = 0
$$
Hence
$$
EY = (1+EY)\times\frac{4}{6}
$$
and $EY =2$.

I think you are on the right track. Let the expected length of the sequence be $E$. We can write an expression for $E$ as follows. With probability $\frac{1}{6}$, we roll a $1$, and the final sequence has length $1$. With probability $\frac{1}{3}$, we roll a number in $\{ 3, 5 \}$, and we are back to the start, where the sequence is expected to have length $E$. With probability $\frac{1}{2}$, an even number is rolled. In this case, the probability that this roll contributes to the final sequence is the probability that $1$ is rolled before a number in $\{ 3, 5 \}$, which is just $\frac{1}{3}$. Otherwise, the roll will not contribute anything to the final sequence. So, we have
$$E = \frac{1}{6} (1) + \frac{1}{3} E + \frac{1}{2} \left( E + \frac{1}{3} \right)$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{6} E = \frac{1}{3} \implies E = \boxed{2}$$
